# Combine required, sometimes and regex in validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I want to implement the following logic:

- The field `bank_info_zip` is required if `bank_info_contact_last_name` or `bank_info_street` or `bank_info_city` has any characters.
- If it contains any chars, it should get matched against the pattern: `\d{5}`
- It should not get matched against the pattern if it is empty.

This is my validation-expression/rule:

```
"bank_info_zip" => "required_with:bank_info_contact_last_name,bank_info_street,bank_info_city|regex:/\d{5}/"
```

I have tried to add `sometimes` but dont understand how that works with `required` as it seems to do the exact opposite/negate its effect.

The example in the docs is this:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);
```

and it makes me question my ability to think logically even more.

Comment: Try adding `nullable` to `bank_info_zip`, because `sometimes` will not validate the field if it is missing

Comment: Thanks, that worked! If you make that an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
request()->validate([
    'bank_info_zip' => [
        'required_with:bank_info_contact_last_name,bank_info_street,bank_info_city',
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::when(request()->bank_info_zip, ['regex:/\d{5}/'])
    ],
]);
```

Resources:

1. [Conditional Validation Rules](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38361)
2. [`required_with:foo,bar,...`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with)